# 503 "Service Unavailable" error for all apps after installing iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis-7, iisnode

After installing **iisnode** on Windows Server 2008 SP2 (32 bit), all previously functioning apps report a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." None of these applications are registering or using the iisnode module.

The application pools are stopped after processing their first request.
The event log reports the error as EventID 5002 with:

*"Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."*

Prior to that error, there are several Warnings as Event ID 3139 with:

*"A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '1688' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number."*

I've given the app pool identity read/execute permissions to the node.exe (v0.8.14), as well as C:\Program Files\iisnode\iisnode.dll.

*If I remove the iisnode module from iis, the sites and app pools run fine.*

Any ideas on how to resolve these errors?

Comment: after or before installing iisnode, I was facing this 503 service unavailable , doesn't matter I have attached w3wp process or not , I tried various edgejs nuget versions as well ... in my case reason was the location were actual code is there hasn't got execute permissions it has read permissions so it was able to read content from js file , when it gets turn of executing and call edge.func in c# , it hanged and stopped Api services. .. thanks P S check permission on main location where code is resided. .. Thanks Hema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to this bug: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/231. The bug is already fixed and a new version of iisnode with the fix will be released shortly.

In the meantime you can use iisnode 0.2.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 or move back to iisnode 0.1.21.

Comment: Removing iisnode v2.0.0 and installing to v0.1.21 worked. Thank you very much for the quick response, and for the overall project. I'm looking forward to upcoming release.

Comment: The v0.2.1 which fixes the problem was just released and can be downloaded from https://github.com/windowsazure/iisnode/downloads

Comment: Thanks. I verified that v0.2.1 fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anybody getting this error in the Windows Event Viewer:

> The Module DLL C:\Program Files\iisnode\iisnode.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

but not using Node, the solution for me was simply edit the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file and remove all lines referencing `iisnode` (there were 2).

Essentially we had synced an old IIS server to a newer one to migrate the code across, and the old server had IISNode installed, but the new one didn't. Since IISNode wasn't actually needed by the app, simply removing the references to it from the IIS config solved the problem for us.